# I need to open a sharepoint document in new tab in browser directly from the sharepoint site we created for this project using jquery calls and html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Attach a click event handler to the document link
  $('.document-link').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default link behavior
    
    // Get the URL of the document
    var documentUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    
    // Open the document in a new tab
    window.open(documentUrl, '_blank');
  });
});
```

Comment: are you using the modern SharePoint experience?